# daily value when cumulative value is known Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I would like to find daily value per date and for product when we know cumulative value. see picture. We know cumulative value and i want to know daily value for each product. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The daily value is the difference between two consecutive cumulative values.

### Example

For example, the daily value on 13/APR/2020 is given by the cumulative value on 13/APR/2020 minus the cumulative value on 12/APR/2020 (the previous day).

### Assumption

I assume the cumulative value is in your data source because if you calculated the cumulative values in DAX it would mean you have daily values available in your data source.

### Solution

You need a `lag function` to obtain the cumulative value on **the previous day** and then calculate the difference between the two cumulative values as explained in my example. You can simply do this calculation in your data source and read an additional data column in PBI.
Instead, if my assumption is wrong, you can define a Calculated Column to reproduce lag behaviour as [explained here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Dax-to-Sql-Windowing-Lag-function-Over-partition-by-equivalent/td-p/387698) by a Microsoft employee.

Without more information on your data model, I can only copy here his general answer for `lag` using **calculated columns**:

```
Lag_Value= 
VAR myID = 'Table1'[ID]
VAR myLastDate = MAXX(FILTER('Table1','Table1'[ID]=myID && 'Table1'[Date] < EARLIER('Table1'[Date])),'Table1'[Date])
RETURN
SUMX(FILTER('Table1','Table1'[Date] = myLastDate && 'Table1'[ID] = myID),'Table1'[Cumulative Value])
```